# Carry a variable into a function in php

Tags: php, function, variables, woocommerce, scope

I'm having problems with variable scope and functions. If a substitute my variable by a string it functions so my problem really seems bring the variable into the function.

```
$this_project_ID =  $get_project_id[0]->ID;
echo $this_project_ID; //This prints out correctly an integer

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function($input, $key ) {
    global $this_project_ID;

    switch ($key) :
        case 'billing_project_id':  
            return $this_project_ID; //This doesn't resolve unless I use a string
        break;
    endswitch;
    }, 10, 2);
```

What don't I understand about bringing variable in a function or is it because this particular function requires something else? Thanks in advance.

So here is the solution thanks to you all and particularly @dmitry.

```
this_project_ID = $get_project_id[0]->ID;

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function($input, $key ) use ( $this_project_ID ) {
switch ($key) :
    case 'billing_project_id':
        return $this_project_ID; 
        break;
endswitch;
```

}, 10, 2);

I used Dmitry's solution and I just got rid of:

```
global $this_project_ID;
```

This is the first time I've seen *use* so I have a lot more to learn. Thanks

Comment: You are adding a _filter_ here, so that means you function will be executed somewhere else - and in _that_ context, your `$this_project_ID` variable presumably does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. To overcome this I need to put this variable in a session or in a superglobal ?

Comment: @Rich Use the `use` keyword `function($input, $key) use (&$this_project_ID){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
this_project_ID = $get_project_id[0]->ID;

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function($input, $key ) use ( $this_project_ID ) {

    switch ($key) :
        case 'billing_project_id':
            return $this_project_ID; 
            break;
    endswitch;
}, 10, 2);
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct. From PHP 7.1, these variables must not include superglobals, $this, or variables with the same name as a parameter.